# При обучении и проверке на корректность нейронной сети с помощью Deeplearning4j один класс все время выкидывается из рассмотрения

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

Использую Deeplearning4j на java. При попытке обучить и проверить бинарный классфифкатор пишет:[image: Вывод программы]

Перед обучением сгенерировал свою достаточно большую выборку(170000 записей),где есть и 0 и 1 в достаотчном количестве в качестве ответа.

Прикладываю свой код нейронной сети

```
public class Network {

private static final int CLASSES_COUNT = 2;
private static final int FEATURES_COUNT = 1000;

public void train() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int seed = 123456;

    int numInputs = 1000;
    int numOutputs = 2;
    int numHiddenNodes = 2 * numInputs + numOutputs;
    double learningRate = 0.005;

    RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(0, ',');
    recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(new ClassPathResource("data.csv").getFile()));
    DataSet allData;

    System.out.println("start to read data");
    DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, 17000, FEATURES_COUNT, CLASSES_COUNT);
    allData = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("read all data");
    allData.shuffle();

    SplitTestAndTrain testAndTrain = allData.splitTestAndTrain(0.65);
    DataSet trainingData = testAndTrain.getTrain();
    DataSet testData = testAndTrain.getTest();

    System.out.println("splitted data start to build configuration");
    MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .biasInit(1)
            .l2(1e-4)
            .updater(new Nesterovs(learningRate, 0.9))
            .list()
            .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(numInputs).nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation(Activation.RELU)
                    .build())
            .layer(1, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(numHiddenNodes).nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation(Activation.RELU)
                    .build())
            .layer(2, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                    .nIn(numHiddenNodes).nOut(numOutputs).build())
            .build();

    MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
    model.init();

    System.out.println("compiled configuration");
    System.out.println("start to fit model");
    /*DataSet allData2;
    DataSetIterator iterator2 = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, 1700, FEATURES_COUNT, CLASSES_COUNT);
    */

    //for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    iterator.reset();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        allData = iterator.next();
        allData.shuffle();
        model.fit(allData.getFeatures(), allData.getLabels());
    }
    //System.out.println("ended epoch number : " + i);
    //}
    System.out.println("fit ended start evaluating");

    INDArray output = model.output(testData.getFeatures());

    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(CLASSES_COUNT);
    eval.eval(testData.getLabels(), output);
    System.out.println(eval.stats());

    //File locationToSave = new File("");
    model.save(new File("mynet.zip"));

    recordReader.close();

}}
```

Прошу подсказать что не так.